# Find the (second) largest value of a named range with a #VALUE!-error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range called "ABI_Volume_Exposure" with numeric values and some #VALUE!-errors and I would like to retrieve the largest (and additionally, the second-largest) value within this named range.
I use the following *array* function:

```
=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(ABI_Volume_Exposure),ABI_Volume_Exposure),1)
```

However, the function doesn't work properly as it shows 0 as output while there is for example a value of 150 in the named range.

If I evaluate the function:

```
=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(ABI_VOLUME_EXPOSURE),ABI_VOLUME_EXPOSURE),1)

=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(#VALUE!),ABI_VOLUME_EXPOSURE),1)

=LARGE(IF(FALSE,ABI_VOLUME_EXPOSURE),1)

=LARGE(IF(FALSE,1)

=0
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Huib

Comment: Hi, formula is fine you just need to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to confirm it rather than just Enter as you want to use an array (more than one cell), also to get second largest use 2 not 1 as your parameter in the LARGE function

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I did entered the formula as an array function and it still doesn't work

Comment: As @maxhob17 said - it worked as an array formula as does `{=MAX(IFERROR(ABI_Volume_Exposure,0))}`

Comment: That's odd, if you entered it as an array formula the evaluate function should have something along the lines of `LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER({1;2;3;#VALUE!;5}),ABI_Volume_Emposure),1)` Are curly braces { and } appearing arround your formula?

Comment: Yes, the curly braces are present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/605702-ignoring-na-formula.html

The Excel 2010 Aggregate function will work without using an array formula:
`=AGGREGATE(4,3,ABI_Volume_Exposure)`

`4` tells it to return the maximum value.
`3` tells it to ignore hidden rows, error values, nested subtotals and aggregate functions.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly and it is way faster than an array function!

Comment: To find the second largest: `=AGGREGATE(14,6,ABI_Volume_Exposure,2)` @HJA24

Comment: @Scott Well that was surprisingly easy - I completely ignored the `[k]` argument.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error with this -> `()`.

I have tried this formula and it works fine.

In `A1` I have a numeric value 1123.

And in the cell `B1` I have this formula:

```
=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you! Still, if I use your formula `=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(ABI_Volume_Exposure),ABI_Volume_Exposure,1))`. I get a message that I've entered too few arguments for this function